# How to filter string array from first index rather then containing char?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, filter, collections

I have an array of countries. I need to search and update array with searched text but starting with initial char match not anywhere in the string.

For eg: If I search in it should return India, Indonesia... not ChINa...

I have created bleow method which looks into whole string rather then initial char.

Also, I don't have any range in this function so how can I get range from string?

```
func searchCountry(for string: String) {
        if !string.isEmpty {
            let filtered = countries?.filter {
                $0.name?.range(of: string,
                               options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
            }
            guard let filteredCountries = filtered else { return }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $0.name?.range(of: string,options: [.anchored, .caseInsensitive]) != nil
```

Use anchored to search the initials. It starts from the start.

Comment: This is much more efficient than `lowercased().hasPrefix( ... .lowercased()`.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use this for appropriate output

```
func searchCountry(for string: String?) {
        if let searchText = string {
            let filter = countries.filter({ $0.lowercased().hasPrefix(searchText.lowercased()) })
            print(filter)
        }
    }
```